# How to use database to create REST Api in Spring Mvc

Tags: database, postgresql, rest, spring-mvc

I am naive on this because we recently start learning API. Previously I worked with Database but Never create a API using the database. We use Postgres for database. If anyone has any idea about creating JDBC DAO class using Database and to create API controller that will be really helpful. Thank you......Any idea can be useful.

Comment: Look into spring-data-jpa, spring-web.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot you can define the DB details in the config file(application.yml or application.properties)

```
spring:
 datasource:
  url: jdbc:postgresql://{host}:{port-default:5432}/{dbname}?currentSchema= {schemaName}
  username: {username}
  password: {password}
  platform: postgres
```

- https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Also, you can refer [spring-data-jpa](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa#overview)